# Closed Caption to text file using directshow graphedit

Tags: windows, directshow, codec, closed-captions, graphedit

I want to capture cc(closed caption) as plain text to text file; using directshow, graphedt.

I have used VBICodec and Dump filter. My graph is as follow

Ospray Capture Device (has 4 output pin:Capture, Preview, CC, VBI) -> Tee/Sink-to-Sink

Converter -> VBI Codec -> ClosedCaptions.txt(dump filter).

the file has encoded data and not the plain text.

how can i save closedcaption to text file ? (i have windows 2008 server)

Answer (score 1):

The Osprey (and likely any other capture card that supports NTSC and ATSC captions) outputs [EIA-608](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIA-608) format. It has special character sets and control codes that have to be converted to whatever format you need.

Unfortunately I don't know of any readily available DirectShow filters that will convert this to a text format for you so you'll probably have to write one.